# Non rigid transformation between 2 differents 3D meshes

Tags: 3d, transformation, mesh, head

I'm looking for an optimal method to match vertices of 2 different meshes. Different in density, size and maybe some other reasons.

The 2 meshes represent a human head, so the anatomical differences can be many.

The problem is minimization. Maybe minimization of mean distance or energy.

I can find on the web a few methods for registration interest point in 2D images, but not in 3D.

Does anyone have an idea for a non-rigid transformation?

I'm working especially to find each dual vertex of a vertex of each mesh in the other one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the paper below works for different number of points but you can check the following paper

GLOBAL CORRESPONDENCE OPTIMIZATION FOR NON-RIGID REGISTRATION OF DEPTH SCANS
Hao Li, Robert W. Sumner, Mark Pauly